# Correctly rebasing git branch

Tags: git, github

I have a branch history something like the following:

develop --- o ---- o 
   | 
 feature

I wanted to make changes in the feature branch, so I did the following

```
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git fetch origin feature:feature
git rebase develop
```

Then I made my changes in the feature branch.
Now, I try to push the feature branch and I get

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/test/test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

This is probably due to the remote branch not being rebased. What is the correct way to solve this problem? I dont want to use `git push -f`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `develop` local branch is upto date with the remote `develop` branch here is what you need to do

```
git checkout feature
git rebase origin/develop
git push origin feature --force
```

what you are doing above is , you rebasing your local `feature` branch with the local `develop` branch since , we assumed that your local and remote `develop` branches are now the same .

Also another point i want to make is , when you pull from the remote , always try to pull and rebase . So that you always know that your local `<branchname>` and remote `<branchname>` have identical copies and you don't need to do a separte rebase . here is how you do that.

```
git checkout <branchname>
git pull --rebase origin <branchname>
```